# Post an object with jQuery instead of query strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to send a post to a service with jQuery, the url seems something like this:
www.domain.com/api/service?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3

and I want to send an object like this

```
{
param1 = "value1",
param3 = "value2",
param3 = "value3"
}
```

as Angular, but I do not want to use Angular because it would be involve a large and expensive migration.

This could be posible?

Comment: check `$.ajax`. Here is the link http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do a `POST` instead of a `GET`.

The first URL you listed is a `GET`, where the query string is appended directly to the URL.

A `POST` doesn't have the parameters in the URL. Instead, it includes them as the *request body* in the HTTP request itself.

With `jQuery.ajax()`, it's a simple matter of specifying the `method` option to `POST` (it defaults to `GET`) and provide the `data` object with your request body:

```
jQuery.ajax({ url: 'myurl.com', method: 'POST', data: myDataToSend });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourObj = {
    param1: 'value1',
    param2: 'value2',
    param3: 'value3',
}
```

With `POST`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: /* your url */
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: yourObj,
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

With `GET`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: /* your url */
    method: 'GET',
    data: yourObj,
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Read for more options [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

for get request :

```
$.get( "url", { 
 param1:"value1",
 param3:"value2",
 param3:"value3" 
} );
```

for post request:

```
$.post( "url", { 
 param1:"value1",
 param3:"value2",
 param3:"value3" 
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `POST` instead of `GET`:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: 'your_url',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        param_1 : 'value'
        ...
    }
}).done(function(response)
{
    //parse the response here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you define yourObj which is a json object here note that json object required the key and value with double quetos for string yjen with ajax send this object to the server the function stringify is to create a string of your json object

```
var yourObj = {
        "param1": "value1",
        "param2": "value2",
        "param3": "value3",
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(yourObj),
        url: /* your url */
    });
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your answer to avoid deletion.